# How can I blur everything around an element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, blur

Let's take [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as an example. How can you blur every element on the page (below the header navigation) except for one selected element ON the page (which should receive focus)?

If you blur the entire content area, the focused element will be blurred too (you can't unblur a child of a blurred parent). And if you select (and check) every single element whether it should be blurred or not can't be the best way to do so. Also, the element should stay within the content area and not be transformed HTML-wise in any way.

This:
[image]

Should become this (with CSS only):
[image]

It would be easy to just darken it with an absolute positioned overlay and give the focused element a `relative` position with a higher `z-index`, but unfortunately, blurring that dark overlay does not blur the content behind it:
[image]

Comment: Well most time people add elements to surround the element and apply filters to those or add one and alter z-index.

Comment: Other option is to walk the tree and do not apply the blur to add parent, just apply it to other branches and siblings.

Comment: use backdrop-filter to blur everything with a huge masking div, use z-index to elevate anything you want to save above the mask.

Comment: `.highlight::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);`

Comment: Some people just like to give a `-1` to questions for no apparent reason, I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `backdrop-filter` solved this issue, thank you @Sheraff and @epascarello 23

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the container of what you're hovering and add a :not(:hover) to it.

This is from a codepen of mine: https://codepen.io/amandaIaria/pen/vqdONB. I've just turned it into CSS instead of the SCSS version, and removed anything that is not needed. It might not be 100% of the use case, but it's how I did it.

```css
.project-container:hover .project:not(:hover) {
  // You might not need this overflow but just in case
  overflow: hidden;
}

// This rule basically says when you are hovering the container and if the specific project is not the specific one you are hoving add the blur to the content.

.project-container:hover .project:not(:hover) .project__content {
       // All the blurs
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
        -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -o-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px); 
        filter: url(#blur); 
        filter: blur(5px);   
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3') grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: This would work with a focused (instead of hovered) element too I guess?

Comment: It might. I've never tried it with a :focus though.

Comment: The idea would be to use it someday like this `details:has(> summary:focus) {
  /* Exclude this element from blurring */
}`

Comment: However, I like your idea and will perhaps rethink my concept...